# Solving an NMR Schrodinger equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

Fairly standard differential equations question. I always struggled with this as an undergrad because I skipped the diff. eq. math course. It has obviously come back to bite me.

I am trying to solve the Schrodinger equation in a nuclear magnetic resonance setting (constant magnetic field along one axis, AND oscillating magnetic field along the other 2 axes).

My objective is the solve the following differential equation for $x(t)$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\dot{x}(t) &=& \frac{i}{2}[\omega_0 x(t) + \omega_1 e^{i\omega t} y(t)] \\
\dot{x}(t) -\frac{i}{2}\omega_0 x(t) &=& \frac{i}{2}\omega_1 e^{i\omega t} y(t)
\end{eqnarray*}

the differing orders, $x(t)$ but also its time derivative are throwing me for a loop.

Another level of complexity enters the game in that $y(t)$ is not a fixed and known value. I.e. the solutions are coupled. I aim to solve the following as well as the one written above

\begin{eqnarray*}
\dot{y}(t) &=& \frac{i}{2}[\omega_1 e^{-i\omega t}x(t) - \omega_0  y(t)] \\
\dot{y}(t) +\frac{i}{2}\omega_0 y(t) &=& \frac{i}{2}\omega_1 e^{-i\omega t} x(t)
\end{eqnarray*}

For instance, in other circumstances, like solving the Schrodinger equation in a simpler magnetic field background (only one field oscillating along only one axis), I have no trouble solving the following differential equation for $x(t)$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\dot{x}(t) &=& \frac{i}{2} \omega_0 \cos (\omega t) x(t) \\
\frac{1}{x}\frac{d x}{dt} &=& \frac{i}{2} \omega_0 \cos (\omega t) \\
\frac{1}{x} d x  &=& \frac{i}{2} \omega_0 \cos (\omega t) dt\\
ln (x) + C  &=& \frac{i\omega_0}{2\omega} \sin (\omega t) + C' \\
x e^C  &=& e^{\frac{i\omega_0}{2\omega} \sin (\omega t)}e^{C'} \\
x(t) &=& e^{\frac{i\omega_0}{2\omega} \sin (\omega t)}(e^{C'}/e^C) \\
&=& e^{\frac{i\omega_0}{2\omega} \sin (\omega t)} C^{''} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

where I can find $C^{''}$ from initial conditions. Moreover, the second equation in THIS system is uncoupled to the first,

$$
\dot{y}(t) = -\frac{i}{2} \omega_0 \cos (\omega t) y(t) 
$$

which is solved in exactly the same fashion as above.